# Can I use a JS Grid layout library like Gridstack with Blazor ? If yes how?

Tags: javascript, blazor, responsive, webassembly, gridstack

I want to create a Dashboard in blazor where I can use resizable and movable widgets for which I want a grid structure . Unfortunately there is no such library for blazor out of the box . Can anyone suggest and show if we can use a library such as Gridstack for this with blazor?

Answer (score 0):

Blazor can do anything you can do with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. To achieve something like this, you'll want to look into Blazor's JavaScript interoperability e.g., `IJSRuntime` service and `[JSInvokable]` attribute. Using these will allow you to communicate between Blazor (WASM or Server) and the browser (JavaScript).

Here's the documentation on getting started with `IJSRuntime` (.NET to JavaScript): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Here's the documentation on getting started with `[JSInvokable]` (JavaScript to .NET): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0